# Large amount of packet loss with new network setup - cables or switches ?

Tags: cabling

I'm struggling after making some network changes to my home - I have a large amount of packet loss in the new setup from hosts on the ground floor and 1st floor to hosts on the internet.

I recently had new cabling run in my house from ground floor to the loft, ground floor to 1st floor and 1st floor to the loft. This is passed the tests on their meter, but it was a relatively simple tester.

The switches are all netgear GS108 prosafe switches. From recent reading, these do not implement any form of spanning tree protocol.

In the failing scenario, I have the following:

My DSL connection comes into a DSL modem on the ground floor. My firewall and servers are in the loft.

The DSL modem connects to a port on the firewall using ethernet (PPPoE). Another port from that firewall plugs into a switch. Also connected to that switch are 2 servers and 2 switches (one switch on ground floor and one switch on 1st floor). Connected to the ground floor switch are the TV, a PS3 and an Xbox. On the 1st floor, I have 3 PCs connected to the switch there.

http://pingtest.net/ shows between 1 and 10% packet loss and pings to noc.uk.pingtest.net show similar packet loss. This is only from hosts on the ground floor and 1st floor. Other hosts connected to the switch that the firewall is connected to in the loft have no packet loss.

One thing that that makes me believe that the cables are not the problem is that in the working scenario the cable linking the switch on the ground floor to the equipment in the roof is the path that servers from the loft use to get out and no packet loss is shown.

Working Network
[image: Working network]

Network setup with packet loss
[image: Network Setup with packet loss]

Answer (score 0):

Start from the begging and work your way out.  You mention that all the equipment in the loft is working correctly with no packet loss.  If you do not think it is the cabling, take the switch from the loft and swap it with one of the switches from the locations experiencing the packet loss.  Try unplugging one of the two switches that are experiencing the packet loss.  Does this correct the packet loss on the other switch?  From your drawing it looks like you have several wall junctions, try plugging directly into said junction and see if the equipment still has packet loss.  Check the junctions and make sure the connections are good, are they punched down cleanly.  You need to eliminate possibilities one by one and you will find the offender.  Don't rule out the cable if it is sharing conduit with electrical cable, and or running over or near magnetic ballasts.

Comment: My query on the switches is more about if this problem could be a result of dumb switches (no stp) instead of managed switches. Could this be a result of a network loop ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be cabling, it might be a borderline switch... but since those are dummy switches, you cannot log into them to look for errors so you have to do it another way

Check the interface of those devices reporting packet loss, there might be some errors on those ports.

To help you segment the problem, if you have a laptop, connect it to each switch and try pinging from it (while still watching for ethernet errors) at some point you should be able to pinpoint from where you're loosing data.

Don't forget to ping before and after the firewall and to test every subnets.

Also, don't forget that dummy switches are auto-negotiate.  Check your NICs to see exactly what they're supporting and how they're configured (they all should be auto-negotiating in your particular setup).  In auto-negotiation, Gigabit ports defaults to FULL duplex if the remote device doesn't negotiate, while 100mb and 10mb ports default to HALF duplex.